# Modify the packing box scaling model and it is stretched incorrectly. How to scale it correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

`https://www.packola.com/pages/tool?sku=SHIPBOX-ST:RSC-L:12-W:12-D:12-MT:WHT-FLT:B-CL:40-TA:10-QTY:250&page_id=25&page_revision_id=10414`

The above is the case I want to simulate. The length, width and height of the packaging box model can be modified, and the lid on the top has the correct proportion.

`https://codesandbox.io/s/fabric-three-forked-25r4dt?file=/index.js:0-8602[text]`

This is a similar case I found but he had the following problem

[This is the rendering of how I imported the model into three.js and modified the zoom factor of the z-axis of the box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlrhB.png)
Apparently the top lid of the box was stretched incorrectly;

How should I modify it or is there any better case?

How can I fix the problem in this case?